# Store location with some excluded path

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

This code stores the last know location in the session. The location is not stored if it is one of the exceptions in the `if` statement.

```
def store_location
    if request.fullpath != '/users/sign_in' &&
     request.fullpath != '/users/sign_up' &&
     request.fullpath != '/users/password' &&
     request.fullpath != '/users/sign_out' &&
     request.fullpath != '/accounts' &&
     request.fullpath != '/accounts/new' &&
     !request.fullpath.include?('/users/confirmation') &&
     request.fullpath != '/' &&
     !request.xhr?

     session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
   end
  end
```

I need to make it more simple.

Answer (score 2):

this is already simple, it follows Devise wiki: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)

but if you really want to make it shorter and remove "if" you can use skip_before_filter on controller level, i.e.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :store_last_page, only: [:new, :index]
```

Comment: I have to say I am surprised that the official docs of Devise advice to use hardcoded paths.